# Can't get value from Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return-value, angular-promise

I'm using AngularJs in a big proyect. I need to create a page that loads a video, said video URL comes from a GET request to the backend.

This is a very newbie question, but I cannot figure it out!

This is the function that GET the video URL:

```
function getInstructionalVideoUrl() {
  var url = baseUrl + 'instructionalvideo';
  return $http.get(url)
    .then(success)
    .catch(fail);

  function fail(response) {
    exception.catcher('XHR Failed for start setup')(response.data);
    return $q.reject(response);
  }

  function success(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

When I assign the result of that function to a variable and I log that variable to the console, this is what I get:

[image: Promise value]

How can I get THAT value? Is this function returning a Promise?

I'm failing to recognize exactly what I am getting back.

Comment: What does ```console.log(response)``` show you?

Comment: you need to call `.then()` on the return, and do the stuff that needs the data inside of that `then` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the angular documentation on promises with some examples: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

At first glance, the getInstructionalVideoUrl doesn't seem to be passing back the promise correctly in the success case.  If it were you could do something like this...

```
getInstructionalVideoUrl()
.then(function(video){
//read the video
}, 
function(error){
/*handle error*/
});
```

Comment: It was actually returning a promise. So a treated it like one and everything worked like a charm :)